# Solr data import handler from multiple database tables

Tags: apache, solr, solr4

I have a problem in importing data using data import handler in Solr from multiple database tables residing on completely different databases. One table is from an on premise oracle database and the other is from an Oracle RDS cloud database.

My data import handler query is:

```sql
select 
  emp.eid, emp.ename, dept.deptid, dept.dname
from 
  emp inner join dept on emp.deptid = dept.deptid
```

Now this `dept` table is moved to another database.

In this scenario how can I index the data from multiple database tables.

Comment: could you please add more information? what do you mean from multiple database tables?

Comment: @Mysterion thanks for ur reply.my scenario is one table is from onprem oracle database and another is from Oracle RDS cloud database). completely different databases.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a problem that Solr will help you to solve. You should tackle this with an [Oracle Database Link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083). You need to create the database link within the database server that wants to connect to the `dept` table. After that create a view or materialized view within the database with the link for Solr to fetch the data from. That view should use the query that you have shown to us, with small changes due to the natuer of database links. Then you can create a dataimport handler within Solr to fetch and import your data from that view. Solr shouldn't need to know that there is more than one database server involved.

If you have trouble doing this, head over to [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle)